# How to deal with null values when counting strings in python

Tags: python, pandas, count

I am trying to count the number of words from each cell of a column using this code:

```
df['count_string'] = df.col_with_strings.apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(';')))
```

The code is working great excepting  the case when I have no value in column 'col_with_strings', in this case returns '1' even though there's no string in the cell so it should return '0' as the correct result.

Is there a way to update/correct the line of code above in order to obtain the correct output?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a space in the "empty" column?  (Len(' ') will return 1, and it will also return one for at least some other whitespace (\n \t) characters.)  One other thing--Python does not have null, it has None, and len(None) will throw an error.

Comment: @themagicbean `str(None)` returns the string "None", and splitting that on semicolons gives a list of length 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can include an if clause:

```
df['count_string'] = df.col_with_strings.apply(lambda x: 0 if not x else len(str(x).split(';')))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for apply, pandas has in-built functions - `str.split` and `str.len` - to take care of this for you:

```
# Example
df

     col
0  a;b;c
1    b;c
2      c
3    NaN

df['col'].str.split(';').str.len()

0    3.0
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

If you instead want the NaN to be filled with 0, use `fillna`:

```
df['col'].str.split(';').str.len().fillna(0, downcast='infer')

0    3
1    2
2    1
3    0
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

---

Another simple option is to count the separator and add 1 to get the count of words:

```
df['col'].str.count(';').add(1).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

0    3
1    2
2    1
3    0
Name: col, dtype: int64
```